# Color Picker terminal launch

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I want to set a keyboard shortcut to launch Color Picker (by Ronny Dobra from the AppCenter) but don't know what the terminal command would be for it.

1) What command will launch Color Picker from the terminal?

2) How can I find terminal command to launch other applications I may want for the same purposes?

Comment: Could u please tell, if by using the command > color-picker Can you open the application?

Comment: color-picker in the terminal doesn't work, unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a text editor like code for example, then drag the icon of the color picker from the app launcher to the text editor, this will open the shortcut file for the app, the search for the line that starts like "Exec=", you will get something like this:
"Exec=com.github.jmoerman.go-for-it"

the part after the "=" is the comand to execute the color picker

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you tried just hitting the windows(super key)
then go to setting it the top right cnr
then to custom
then just add new and tell it what you want it to do

Comment: Yes I know how to do that, but not the exact command